# How can I invoke a method of Qt Quick 2 Extension Plugin?

Tags: c++, qt, qtquick2

I have a Subdirs project, there are two subprojects. One is a Qt Quick Controls 2 Application, and other is a Qt Quick 2 Extension Plugin.

```
TestQtQuickPlugin    ( Subdirs project )
    |----app         ( Qt Quick Controls 2 Application )
    |     |------main.cpp
    |    ...
    |----plugin      ( Qt Quick 2 Extension Plugin )
    |       |----MyItem.h
    |       |----MyItem.cpp
    |      ...
```

MyItem class inherits from QQuickItem, and it has a method **int getNum()**. In main method, I will invoke this method by **MyItem().getNum()**.

In Ubuntu, it compiles and runs successful. But in Windows, it occurs error:

> main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl MyItem::MyItem(class QQuickItem *)" (??0MyItem@@QEAA@PEAVQQuickItem@@@Z) referenced in function main
>
> main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl MyItem::~MyItem(void)" (??1MyItem@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
>
> main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl MyItem::getNum(void)" (?getNum@MyItem@@QEAAHXZ) referenced in function main

What is wrong with my project?

Comment: Are you sure you want to create an instance of a `QQuickItem` derived class in C++?

Comment: @KevinKrammer No, I just want call a static method of that class

Comment: Ah, ok, your syntax is creating an temporary instance and calling a method on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows uses "symbol hiding" when creating dynamically linked libraries.

In order for symbols to be "visible" outside such a library they need to be "exported".

See the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sharedlibrary.html) here.

This can actually also be enabled on Linux by setting a respective flag for g++.